# React Testing Library - existence / assertion best practice

Tags: react-testing-library

When testing for the existence of an element, is it recommended to always assert as in:

`expect(await screen.findByTestId('spinner')).toBeVisible();`

Or is it sufficient (recommended) to just wait for the element:

`await screen.findByTestId('spinner');`

Note: the spinner is added using React Hooks and that is why I am await'ing them.

I thought a previous version of RTL recommended not specifically asserting when not required, but I can't find any references to that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certain Testing Library queries as `getBy` or `findBy` that have an implicit "expect". What happens is that they would throw an error in case the element is not found, so as you say, you can either wrap it in an expect or just do a simple query and if the test passes, that means the query didn't throw any errors.

You can see the explicit assertion as a feeling that you are checking something in that specific line. That way you can have more differentiate sections (Arrange, Act, Assert or "render, do things, expect things") that look almost the same in every test no matter what they are expecting.

Testing Library tends to recommend best practices when doing queries as they are built for a reason and each query can give you better results (for example you could test more things doing a `queryByRole` with a `name` option than doing a simple `queryByName`. However, this question would be a matter of "styling" in your code, and they can only say you could go with the "always write an expect" option if you want all your tests to be more uniform.